# Rsync exclude and include problem; include file in excluded directory

Tags: rsync

I want to do the following with `rsync`.

Directory structure example

- home/netadmin/docker-data
- home/netadmin/docker-data/uptime-kuma/
- home/netadmin/docker-data/uptime-kuma/error.log

I want to `rsync` the `docker-data` directory but want to exclude the `home/netadmin/docker-data/uptime-kuma/` directory but want to include `home/netadmin/docker-data/uptime-kuma/error.log`.

I'm using the following command :

```
rsync -av --delete --include-from='/home/netadmin/include.txt' --exclude-from='/home/netadmin/exclude.txt' /home/netadmin/docker-data /home/netadmin/temp/
```

The directory is being excluded but the file is not copied.

My question is, is it possible?

This is how my include and exclude files look like :

exclude.txt

```
uptime-kuma/
```

include.txt

```
+ error.log
```

Comment: wouldn't you need `uptime-kuma/error.log`? Since it's looking relative to the directory the transfer is in (`/home/netadmin/docker-data`)

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" is to *not* exclude the `uptime-kuma` directory, but its contents.

With an include pattern of `error.log` and an exclude pattern of `uptime-kuma/*`, you would include the file `uptime-kuma/error.log` before excluding everything else in that subdirectory.

With `uptime-kuma/` instead of `uptime-kuma/*`, you would exclude the directory, and `rsync` would never look inside it.

```bash
rsync -av --delete \
    --include=error.log \
    --exclude='uptime-kume/*' \
    ~netadmin/docker-data ~netadmin/temp/
```

I hope this is an equivalent test:

```bash
$ tree
.
`-- topdir
    |-- file-1
    |-- file-2
    |-- file-3
    |-- file-4
    |-- file-5
    `-- subdir
        |-- file-a
        |-- file-b
        |-- file-c
        |-- file-d
        |-- file-e
        `-- myfile

2 directories, 11 files
```

```bash
$ rsync -av --include=myfile --exclude='subdir/*' topdir/ copydir
sending incremental file list
created directory copydir
./
file-1
file-2
file-3
file-4
file-5
subdir/
subdir/myfile

sent 436 bytes  received 171 bytes  1,214.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

```bash
$ tree copydir
copydir
|-- file-1
|-- file-2
|-- file-3
|-- file-4
|-- file-5
`-- subdir
    `-- myfile

1 directory, 6 files
```

---

As a tip: You will get the reasoning behind why `rsync` includes or excludes things if you use `-vv`.

This is using the "wrong" exclusion pattern:

```bash
$ rm -r copydir
$ rsync -avv --include=myfile --exclude='subdir/' topdir/ copydir
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding directory subdir because of pattern subdir/
created directory copydir
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
./
file-1
file-2
file-3
file-4
file-5
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 326 bytes  received 211 bytes  1,074.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

This is using the "correct" exclusion pattern:

```bash
$ rm -r copydir
$ rsync -avv --include=myfile --exclude='subdir/*' topdir/ copydir
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding file subdir/file-a because of pattern subdir/*
[sender] hiding file subdir/file-b because of pattern subdir/*
[sender] hiding file subdir/file-c because of pattern subdir/*
[sender] hiding file subdir/file-d because of pattern subdir/*
[sender] hiding file subdir/file-e because of pattern subdir/*
[sender] showing file subdir/myfile because of pattern myfile
created directory copydir
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
./
file-1
file-2
file-3
file-4
file-5
[generator] risking file subdir/myfile because of pattern myfile
subdir/
subdir/myfile
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 436 bytes  received 307 bytes  1,486.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an other method. I use

```shell
cp --parents
```

option to copy only the specific files I want in the excluded directories and also to keep the directory structure.